# Requestlist throws heap out of memory in apify for more than 10 million wordlist

Tags: node.js, shell, web-scraping, cron, apify

I have a wordlist of 11 character which I want to append in a url. After some modification in request.js,I am able to run 5 million size wordlist in requestlist array.It start throwing JavaScript heap memory error after going higher.I have billion of size of wordlist to process. I can able to generate my wordlist with js code.5 million entry finishes up in an hour,due to higher server capacityR I possess. Requestlist is a static variable so I cant add again in it.How can I run it infinitely for billions of combination.If any cron script can help then I am open to this also.

Comment: I think `RequestList` loads everything to memory so it may not be optimized for that many records depending on available memory. How much memory are you running the actor with? Is it an option to split up the input list to smaller chunks that could be then processed independently and perhaps re-merged again after?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use [`RequestQueue`](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/guides/request-storage#request-queue) for such a high amount of Requests. The queue is persisted to disk as an SQLite database so memory usage is not an issue.

I suggest adding let's say 1000 requests into the queue and immediately start crawling, while pushing more requests to the queue. Enqueueing tens of millions or billions of requests might take long, but you don't need to wait for that.

For best performance, use `apify` version `1.0.0` or higher.